# Change the rendered output of a Message entity

Tags: 7, message-subscribe

I'm using the [Message module](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) to create messages on certain events, for example, on forum node creation:

"X has posted a new thread in the Y forum."

I've got a view that spits all of these out.

I now want to create a new view that shows the same messages, but in this view, I want to change the output of the above message to:

"You have posted a new thread in the Y forum."

Every time the node's author matches the currently authed user.

---

Now my thoughts would be that I could somehow intercept the output of either the token (X) or override the whole message entity template, but I'm not entirely sure how to go about this.

Another thing I tried was to create a new user token, called "Username or you", which would output "you" if the associated message node matched the authed user, or the username if not. However, I'm not sure how I could get the message object. It's worth noting that I have the token:

```
[message:field-forum-post:author:username_or_you]
```

So if I could follow the trail back to "message" and get the message id, I'd be all set.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Messaging documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180987), specifically [this overview on new features](http://www.gizra.com/content/what-message-module-and-its-new-features/). You likely want to override the tokens provided using a `callback` which is supported by the module:

> Callbacks: sometimes we can’t use the token system, for example if we
>   need to show different results based on the value of _two different
>   fields. This is an advanced feature, which is meant for developers,
>   and is documented in the module.

I've not done this myself yet, but I've used the Message module and Views -- digging through the module and documentation should get you there now that you know it's possible.

From the message_example [README](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/message/tree/message_example/README.txt) it sounds like you want an activity stream:

> The UAS (User activity stream) view is dependent on Panels, as it uses
>   "Panel fields" as a row plugin, along with the Message's partials.

Which you should be able to look at for inspiration in the example module.

Comment: Thanks, callback was the perfect solution as it updates in realtime rather than retrieving from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to (also) use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, you might be able to make a token such as `username_or_you` (as in your question ...) available by using the Replacement patterns for each message type.

So the answer to your question is "***Whatever token you're missing, just make it available via Rules, by creating a replacement token for them***". Refer to the answer to [What's the purpose of "Replacement tokens" of a Message type?](http://drupal.placeto.be/node/109) for way more details on that.

These *Replacement tokens* are really a hidden gem about how Rules integrates with Message. For an example to see them at work, refer to my answer to "[Which user related token(s) can be used to create a Rule for setting up a message type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/219680/39516)".